# Binding mark_geoshape rotate property to slider selection

Tags: altair

I'm trying to recreate something similar to [this vega plot](https://observablehq.com/@manzt/mcv-choropleth-map-with-barchart-using-vega-embed) in Altair.

I've had luck building the `mark_geoshape` maps before when binding to something like `color`, which can be in `encode` function, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to bind the slider to the `rotate` property of the chart, which lives in `project`.

I presumed I could do something like this, but no luck:

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

# Data generators for the background
sphere = alt.sphere()
graticule = alt.graticule()

# Source of land data
source = alt.topo_feature(data.world_110m.url, 'countries')

slider = alt.binding_range(min=0, max=100, step=1, name='rotate:')
selector = alt.selection_single(name="SelectorName", fields=['rotate'],
                                bind=slider, init={'rotate': 180})

# Layering and configuring the components
alt.layer(
    alt.Chart(sphere).mark_geoshape(),
    alt.Chart(graticule).mark_geoshape(stroke='white', strokeWidth=0.5),
    alt.Chart(source).mark_geoshape(fill='ForestGreen', stroke='black')
).project(
    'orthographic',
).encode(
    rotate=['rotate',180,180]
).properties(width=600, height=400, selection=selector).configure_view(stroke=None)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
leo

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to do this in Altair: the Vega-Lite schema only supports constant rotation values. If you wish, you can do this in Vega; there is an example at  https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/projections/.